# Created the new project about SpringBoot can't start

Tags: spring-boot

I using VScode create a new SpringBoot project,and just add spring Web this dependent.The most changes are just add `server.address=8088` in application.properties.But I using Vscode start SpringBoot project get error.

```
2024-03-31T10:05:42.222+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 11840 (E:\毕设\1\Maven project04\demo\target\classes started by 22328 in E:\毕设\1\Maven project04\demo)
2024-03-31T10:05:42.227+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-31T10:05:43.379+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-03-31T10:05:43.392+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-31T10:05:43.393+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-03-31T10:05:43.472+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing 
Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-31T10:05:43.473+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1165 ms
2024-03-31T10:05:43.786+08:00  WARN 11840 --- [demo] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
2024-03-31T10:05:43.800+08:00  INFO 11840 --- [demo] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.    
2024-03-31T10:05:43.816+08:00 ERROR 11840 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:291) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:471) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:260) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:205) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:981) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:249) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) 
~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:235) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:306) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:234) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1046) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]       
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:232) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1368) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]        
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1043) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19] 
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

And my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know how to solve it from which direction.Thank you very much for telling me the answer or direction.

Created many times, hoping to run successfully.

Comment: Can you check if your tomcat server is installed properly ? From error it seems there is some problem with tomcat.